# Apache URL rewriting with masking and includes outside of DocumentRoot

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, masking

I have an Apache 2.2.15 web server with the primary site at `/web/mybiz` which corresponds to `http://mybiz.domain.com`. We now have a new subdomain `http://abc.mybiz.domain.com` with the homepage living at `/web/mybiz/abc/index.html`.

Currently, I have a simple rewrite so when people visit `http://abc.mybiz.domain.com`, they get redirected to `http://mybiz.domain.com/abc/index.html`.  The includes for that homepage live in `/web/mybiz/static` and `/web/mybiz/images`.

I need to have it so that people visiting don't see the URL change in the browser, but I cannot figure out how to make it work and keep the includes all working.

Comment: Are you using .htaccess or adding your rewrite in apache config?

Comment: In the apache config.

Answer (score 1):

The use of a rewrite condition along with a rule to map transparently to the subdirectory should work.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^abc\.mybiz\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/|.*\.html)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /abc/$1 [L]
```

Now when a request for `http://abc.mybiz.domain.com/` or `http://abc.mybiz.domain.com/index.html` is made it will be pulled from the /abc/ subdirectory. This also covers any request for an .html file. Your includes (images/css/javascript)? should be pulled in from their real locations just fine.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html